# formatting typescript output file from 'script' cmd

Tags: linux

I'm trying to keep track of my terminal cmds and output via the 'script' cmd but I wasn't aware it showed newline chars and other special chars.

Is there a switch that 'script' can be run with or some good way to filter out characters such as '^M^' from the capture logs from script?

I tried using ':%s/^M^/ ' in vim but it said the chars don't exist. This is what my typescript file looks like after I've exited:

```
cript started on 2023-09-16 07:50:25-04:00 [TERM="xterm-256color" TTY="/dev/pts/1" COLUMNS="100" LINES="24"]
^[[?2004h^[]0;matt@SERENITY: ~/notes^G^[[01;32mmatt@SERENITY^[[00m:^[[01;34m~/notes^[[00m$ l^M
^[[?2004l^Mcore_dump.md  hacking.md  hacking.md.backup  sep1623.md  signals.md  typescript  wifi.md^M
^[[?2004h^[]0;matt@SERENITY: ~/notes^G^[[01;32mmatt@SERENITY^[[00m:^[[01;34m~/notes^[[00m$ ls^M
^[[?2004l^Mcore_dump.md  hacking.md  hacking.md.backup  sep1623.md  signals.md  typescript  wifi.md^M
^[[?2004h^[]0;matt@SERENITY: ~/notes^G^[[01;32mmatt@SERENITY^[[00m:^[[01;34m~/notes^[[00m$ ls^M
^[[?2004l^Mcore_dump.md  hacking.md  hacking.md.backup  sep1623.md  signals.md  typescript  wifi.md^M
^[[?2004h^[]0;matt@SERENITY: ~/notes^G^[[01;32mmatt@SERENITY^[[00m:^[[01;34m~/notes^[[00m$ set -x^M
^[[?2004l^M^[[?2004h^[]0;matt@SERENITY: ~/notes^G^[[01;32mmatt@SERENITY^[[00m:^[[01;34m~/notes^[[00m$ ls^M
^[[?2004l^M+ ls --color=auto^M
core_dump.md  hacking.md  hacking.md.backup  sep1623.md  signals.md  typescript  wifi.md^M
^[[?2004h^[]0;matt@SERENITY: ~/notes^G^[[01;32mmatt@SERENITY^[[00m:^[[01;34m~/notes^[[00m$ w^H^[[Kfind -f^H^[[K^H^[[K^H^[[K^H^[[K^H^[[K^H^[[Kwher^H^[[K^H^[[K^H^[[K^H^[[K^H^[[Kwhereis typescript^M
^[[?2004l^M+ whereis typescript^M
typescript:^M
^[[?2004h^[]0;matt@SERENITY: ~/notes^G^[[01;32mmatt@SERENITY^[[00m:^[[01;34m~/notes^[[00m$ cat tpy^H^[[K^H^[[Kypescript^M
^[[?2004l^M+ cat typescript^M
^[[?2004h^[]0;matt@SERENITY: ~/notes^G^[[01;32mmatt@SERENITY^[[00m:^[[01;34m~/notes^[[00m$ exit^M
^[[?2004l^M+ exit^M
exit^M

Script done on 2023-09-16 07:52:46-04:00 [COMMAND_EXIT_CODE="0"]
```

And I just want to make it "look better" so without the ^M^ and ^[[?2004h$[]0; characters. Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: You may want to pass the `typescript` file through the `colcrt` command (`colcrt < typescript > output`); see if that gets you what you want.

Comment: the output file after that cmd will just show the script start and end lines, everything else was removed from the file for me